# Merge fields from multiple nested arrays in JSON input into new payload array using Dataweave

Tags: anypoint-studio, dataweave, mulesoft

I am using Anypoint Studio 7.3 and Mule 4.2.

Using the JSON input below, I would like to create new payloads to write to database tables including a payload which builds a list of customers from each record entry in the array to create a list entry looking like this:

```
[{
    recordId,
    customerId
}]
```

and the same for a list of transactions with each list entry looking like this:

```
[{
     recordId
     customerId
     transactionId
}]
```

but when I try to transform the data the field values show either as null or as a list instead of a single field in the object like this:

```
{
    "customers": [{
        "record": "1234",  
        "customerId": [
            "5435e1cd-146d-4aac-9164-4a2d80d5eccd"
        ]
    }]
}
```

instead of this:

```
{
    "customers": [{
        "recordId": "1234",
        "customerId": "5435e1cd-146d-4aac-9164-4a2d80d5eccd"
    }]
}
```

**JSON INPUT:**

```
{
    "records": [{
        "recordId": "1234",
        "customers": [{
            "customerId": "1234",
            "transactions": [{
                "transactionId": "1234",
                "prices": [{
                    "priceId": "1234",
                    "price": 1.00
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to return the list of `customers from each record`

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
payload.records flatMap 
    ((record, index) -> 
        record.customers map ((customer, index) -> 
            {
              recordId: record.recordId,
              customerId: customer.customerId          
            }
        )
    )
```

And for returning `list of transactions with each list entry`

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.records flatMap 
    ((record, index) -> 
        record.customers flatMap ((customer, index) -> 
            customer.transactions map ((transaction, index) -> 
                {
                    recordId: record.recordId,
                    customerId: customer.customerId,
                    transactionId: transaction.transactionId        
                }
            )
        )
    )
```

The key part here is using [flatMap](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dw-core-functions-flatmap) for flattening nesting levels of arrays into one.

Comment: Thanks I hadn't seen the flatMap, I had been looking at flatten.  Thanks for your help.